# Unable to adjust Adsense code in html table dynamically

Tags: html, css, html-table

I create a table to display content dynamically means when someone reduce window size or open web page in smaller screen it adjust the content and not disturb the structure of table. The given below code work nice but when I place Adsense code in a new row the table do not work dynamically.
Give solution only using css.

```css
.oclass {
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: justify;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: auto;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  position: relative;
  padding: 4px 32px 4px 32px;
}

.oclass2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
  width: 20px;
  padding: 4px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.tclass {
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px;
  top: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 1px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.eclass {
  display: none;
}

#qtb1 td {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table id="qtb1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="35px">Q1.</td>
      <td>न्यायमूर्ति यू. सी. बनर्जी आयोग का गठन किया गया ?
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <div class="oclass" id="bdy11" onclick="myFunction('bdy11', 'opn11', 
    'tic11', 'ans1', '1','1')">
          <span class="oclass2" id="opn11">A.</span> गोधरा दंगो की जॉच के लिए
          <span class="tclass" id="tic11"></span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <div class="oclass" id="bdy12" onclick="myFunction('bdy12', 'opn12', 
    'tic12', 'ans1', '2','1')">
          <span class="oclass2" id="opn12">B.</span> सिख दंगो की जॉच के लिए
          <span class="tclass" id="tic12"></span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <div class="oclass" id="bdy13" onclick="myFunction('bdy13', 'opn13', 
    'tic13', 'ans1', '3','1')">
          <span class="oclass2" id="opn13">C.</span> चारा घोटाला की जॉच के लिए
          <span class="tclass" id="tic13"></span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <div class="oclass" id="bdy14" onclick="myFunction('bdy14', 'opn14', 
    'tic14', 'ans1', '4','1')">
          <span class="oclass2" id="opn14">D.</span> कोयला घोटाला की जॉच के लिए
          <span class="tclass" id="tic14"></span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <div class="eclass" id="ans1">
          <strong>Ans:</strong> गोधरा दंगो की जॉच के लिए
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js">
        </script>
        <ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:block; text-align:center;" data-ad-layout="in-article" data-ad-format="fluid" data-ad-client="ca-pub-5674344587011658" data-ad-slot="7222486128"></ins>
        <script>
          (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
        </script>
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```js
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
```

```css
<style>
.oclass{
 border-radius: 4px; 
 text-align:justify; 
 border: 1px solid #000; 
 vertical-align: middle; 
 width:auto; 
 margin-bottom: 1em; 
 position: relative; 
 padding: 4px 32px 4px 32px;
 }

.oclass2{
 position: absolute; 
 left: 0; 
 top: 0; 
 bottom: 0; 
 background: #eee; 
 border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px; 
 width: 20px; 
 padding: 4px; 
 border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.tclass{
 position:absolute; 
 right:2px; 
 top:2px; 
 bottom:0; 
 padding:1px; 
 vertical-align:middle; 
 text-align:center; 
 width:20px; 
 height:20px; 
 border-radius:50%; 
 font-size:20px; 
 color:#fff; 
 line-height:20px;
}

.eclass{
 display:none;
}
#qtb1 td {
    vertical-align:top;
}
</style>
```

```html
<table id="qtb1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="35px">Q1.</td>
<td>न्यायमूर्ति यू. सी. बनर्जी आयोग का गठन किया गया ?
                                                    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><div class="oclass" id="bdy11" onclick="myFunction('bdy11', 'opn11', 
'tic11', 'ans1', '1','1')">
<span class="oclass2" id="opn11">A.</span>
                                                            गोधरा दंगो की जॉच 
के लिए                                                            <span 
class="tclass" id="tic11"></span></div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><div class="oclass" id="bdy12" onclick="myFunction('bdy12', 'opn12', 
'tic12', 'ans1', '2','1')">
<span class="oclass2" id="opn12">B.</span>
                                                            सिख दंगो की जॉच के 
लिए                                                            <span 
class="tclass" id="tic12"></span></div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><div class="oclass" id="bdy13" onclick="myFunction('bdy13', 'opn13', 
'tic13', 'ans1', '3','1')">
<span class="oclass2" id="opn13">C.</span>
                                                            चारा घोटाला की जॉच 
के लिए                                                            <span 
class="tclass" id="tic13"></span></div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><div class="oclass" id="bdy14" onclick="myFunction('bdy14', 'opn14', 
'tic14', 'ans1', '4','1')">
<span class="oclass2" id="opn14">D.</span>
                                                            कोयला घोटाला की 
जॉच के लिए                                                            <span 
class="tclass" id="tic14"></span></div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><div class="eclass" id="ans1">
<strong>Ans:</strong> 
                                                गोधरा दंगो की जॉच के लिए                                                
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
 style="display:block; text-align:center;"
 data-ad-layout="in-article"
 data-ad-format="fluid"
 data-ad-client="ca-pub-5674344587011658"
 data-ad-slot="7222486128"></ins>
</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: dont change the layout of the table